# Generic HTML Form to be filled individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When the user selects an option from the select a get request will be performed and the server will return the html snippet which will be appended to the div with the id forms.

```
<select id="someId" name="someName" class="form-control">
    <!-- Options are filled with an ajax call -->
    <option value="">Select the Type</option>
</select>
<div id="forms">
    <!-- here goes the form -->
</div>
```

The returned html forms vary (~10 different forms).
I don't like this approach very much because I'm having a RESTful webservice and I would have to introduce a custom Accept header or work with a lot of query parameters. At the moment I'm doing the latter.

What I want to do is to collect the inputs of a few forms and just post all the collected parameters in one go because they are only used for one call.

My idea would be to create responsive-tabs with the forms (or just the inputs) inside each tab and surround the tab with just one form and will manually collect the userinput from the tabs and send them to the server.

Does anyone of you know an easier way to face this?

I'm working with jQuery and Bootstrap and the webservice already implements the application/json return type.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to submit the form direct to the webservice? Do a normal post back to the server, validate everything and call the webservice from the server, based on the form that was filled in.

Comment: @ppumkin this is what i'm currently doing but my overall goal is to provide just one form where the user can "submit" (i will collect the values via js) the form uses another form and i will do just one post with all the parameters since they will only be used with one server call.

Comment: Oh right. Well, instead of complicating things and making/filling in another hidden form, post back the values as AJAX. Depends what your server is, but with C# its really easy, especially with MVC. Work out all the details in the server code and return a good or bad response for the user.

Comment: @ppumkin Wouldn't this break the principles of being RESTful?

Comment: I am not sure.. the exact details are vague of what is happening. Maybe im incorrect. Cant tell.